# Failed to use pip3 install package in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python-3.x, pip

Hopefully someone may help me with it. I'm using **ubuntu 14.04** and upgraded python3.4 to python3.5.2.

Then I used

```
pip3 install -r <requirments>
```

to upgrade all package. However, i get lots of error for

````
Failed building wheel for <package name>``` and with following error.


~# pip3 -V
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (python 3.5)
~# python -V
Python 3.5.2

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
  self.run_command(cmd)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
  cmd_obj.run()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 213, in run
  archive_basename = self.get_archive_basename()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 161, in get_archive_basename
  impl_tag, abi_tag, plat_tag = self.get_tag()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 155, in get_tag
  assert tag == supported_tags[0]
AssertionError

----------------------------------------
Failed building wheel for setproctitle
````

Answer (score 0):

i turn out to remove all python3.4 and python2.7, then reisntall python3.5 then solve the problem